# Set image from a String path on viewpagerindicator's iconpageindicator

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I need to change the `iconpageindicator`'s image from the SD Card. So, i need to use a `String` of image path instead of the resource id.

Normally, i did something like this :

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter
```

Where the `IconPagerAdapter` :

```
public interface IconPagerAdapter {
    /**
     * Get icon representing the page at {@code index} in the adapter.
     */
    int getIconResId(int index);

    // From PagerAdapter
    int getCount();
}
```

As you can see, the only supported type is `int` or the resource id, but i need to use a `String`.

Have anyone accomplished this? Please kindly help me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the type from int to String and change set Image Resource in IconPageIndicator to String path